# How to install React Native with react Stable version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am try to install React native with React **Stable version** but it install **React: 16-alpha**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0"
}
```

So How Can i install React-native with React Stable version ?

Comment: why you give me Down vote Please make a comment before make Down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, at least with the current version of React Native. To quote [an issue from their repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13469):

> This is intentional because React Native is released on a monthly cycle and uses the code from Facebook's trunk, which was using React 16 alpha 6 at the time of creating the release branch.
>
> ...
>
> No, RN 0.43 works only with React 16.0.0-alpha.6. Use that precise version.

In other words, you need to use the version of React that matches your version of React Native - for the current release, that's 16.0.0-alpha.6.

EDIT:
As Michael Cheng added in the comments, you can opt to use an earlier version of React Native using the `--version` flag.

```
react-native init --version="0.42.0" ProjectName
```

Comment: Thanks for you Answer.
Now how can I install **RN-42** Thats can I use react-15...
I was try it but nothing i was success.

Comment: @JavaScriptLearner You can create a project using a specific version of RN using the `--version` flag like so: `react-native init --version="0.42.0" ProjectName`

Comment: @MichaelCheng Thank You so much ...... Exact Answer :) 
Please add it in your Answer That i can make it right answer.

Comment: @JavaScriptLearner: Added it, with credit of course :)

Comment: I tried the command it didn't work. You have to say the project name first before the flag `npx react-native init MyProject --version="0.63.4"`

Answer (score 0):

To install React Native, please follow some steps:

1. Install node
2. Check `node --version`, `npm --version`
3. Go the official sites of React Native

https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started

react-native cli quick start, please follow the steps carefully, set all path, if you are using windows, otherwise, you have to start your android studio every time for running the emulator

4. `npx react-native init yourProjectName`
5. `cd yourProjectName` and run, `npx react-native run-android` or `npx react-native run-ios`